# convert NetBIOS name to IP address

Tags: c#, .net

How can I convert a NetBIOS name to an IP address in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses("NAME")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx)